# Heap Bit-Shift Macros for Left, Right and Parent

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, heap

I am reading about Heaps, which describes that you can do the operations of accessing the left child, the **RIGHT**/**LEFT** child and the **PARENT** with bit shift operations. While Left and Parent seems trivial i am not sure with the right one. Do i just have to add one?

Here is an excerpt from the book: MIT Introduciton to algorithms:

"Similarly, the **RIGHT** procedure can quickly compute 2i + 1 by shifting the binary representation of i left by one bit position and then adding in a 1 as the low-order bit".

[image: MIT Introduction to Algorithms - Heap]

**Access Operations:**

LEFT: 2*i

```
i<<1
```

RIGHT: 2*i+1

```
(i<<1)+1
```

PARENT: i/2

```
i>>1
```

Comment: What's wrong? The right child of the node #3 is the node #7, which is `(3 << 1) + 1` **(note the `<< 1`, since `<< 2` multiplies the N by 4)**

Comment: adding in a 1 as the low-order bit in the book sounded for me something more fancy then just doing a **+1**

Comment: The question still a bit unclear for me, but I tried to explain the logic behind `N*2` and `N*2 + 1`. Tell me, if you need more details or explanations

Comment: It's clear...i just didn't do much with bitshifting, i was wondering of my operations are correct.

Comment: Updated answer with notes about bit shifting operations

Answer (score 0):

This is how heap works - for every node you could easily get:

1. Parent - just divide the node index by two (`N / 2`)
2. Left child - multiply index by two (`N * 2`)
3. Right child - multiply index by two and increase new index by one (`N * 2 + 1`)

It is easy to prove, that two distinct nodes cannot have same child.

Suppose, `N1`, `N2` and `C` are heap nodes. `N1 != N2` and `C.is_child_of(N1)` and `C.is_child_of(N2)`, where `C.is_child_of(N)` returns `true` when `C` is either right or left child of `N`. Then:

1. If `C` is the left child of both `N1` and `N2`, then `N1 * 2 = N2 * 2 <=> N1 = N2`
2. Similarly, if `C` is the right child of both `N1` and `N2`, then `N1 * 2 + 1 = N2 * 2 + 1 <=> N1 = N2`
3. If `C` is the left child of `N1` and `C` is the right child of `N2`, then `N1 * 2 = N2 * 2 + 1` which is incorrect, because `N1 * 2` is even and `N2 * 2 + 1` is odd.

---

Note, that your bitwise access operations are incorrect - you should shift indices by one, not by two, because `N << M` is `N * 2^M`. I'd also suggest you to use plain division / multiplication instead of bit shifting - the compiler knows how to optimize your code.

Comment: Note that this is only true if the root of your heap is at index 1 in the array. For a 0-based heap the parent is at `(n-1)/2`, the left child is at `(n*2)+1`, and the right child is at `(n*2)+2`.

Answer (score 0):

A left shift by one bit position on an `Int i` is equivalent to `2*i`

If we consider i as the index of an array:
- the index of the left child can be obtained using:

```
i << 1
```

-the index of the right child

```
(i<<1)+1
```

-The parent:

```
i>>1
```

(equivalent to i/2)

Don't forget we consider on this case that the initial index of the array is 1.